# Flask/JavaScript Error: Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I'm getting this error: Method Not Allowed. The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

The relevant code is:
base.html:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="POST">
    <input id="nav_logout" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Logout">
</form>
```

main.js:

```
function logout(e) {
    console.log('in logout');
    e.preventDefault();

    //posting our data to /api/v1/user
    qwest.post("/api/v1/logout")
        // then runs on success
     .then(function(xhr, response) {
        console.log("logged out user");
        console.log(response);
     })
        // catch runs on fail
     .catch(function(e, xhr, response) {
        console.log('in error');
        console.log(e);
     })
    console.log("completed logout")
}

var logout_button = document.getElementById('nav_logout');
logout_button.addEventListener('click', logout);
```

api.py:

```
@api.route('/api/v1/logout', methods=['POST'])
def logout_route():
    session.clear()
    return redirect(url_for('main.main_route'))
```

I have very similar code working in other places. I've read many similar StackOverflow articles with this same error; many say that the flask code didn't have the right POST/GET methods, but adding GET to my api route didn't help.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: probably obvious, but have you opened your console and checked that this really was a post request?

Comment: Yes, I just verified in Terminal that it tried to do a POST

Comment: Your `<form>` tag does not specify an `action`, therefore it defaults to the current URL, which I assume is something other than `/api/v1/logout`.  Does that URL define a POST handler?

Comment: @JohnGordon My understanding is that specifying that action will completely bypass the JavaScript portion of my code. Adding action="{{url_for('api.logout_route')}} does work, but our instructors say we're not supposed to use the action tag. Instead we have to listen for the click with JavaScript and use JavaScript to POST to the API

Comment: How are you listening for the click?  An `onClick` handler?

Comment: @JohnGordon the 
var logout_button = document.getElementById('nav_logout');
logout_button.addEventListener('click', logout);
code has worked in other places. It listens for a click and runs the logout() function when it hears a click. I also tried including onclick="logout()" which didn't change anything

Comment: Does that completely replace the default click behavior?  Or do you also need to un-register the default behavior?

Comment: So what is the method that is being used? Take a look at the Flask output/logs, or use your browser's web developer extensions to check.